# Add single quotes to user input in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I'm getting zip codes from a text input by the user like this: `23562,12114,13133`

It comes into my PHP with this:

```
$selected_zips =$_POST['chosen_zips'];
```

I need those zip codes to end up in the format below so I can use a prepared statement that I've got working. Here's the format I need:

```
$arr = array('23562','12114','13133');
```

So, basically, I need each zip code placed in single quotes and then a comma in between.

What's the best way to do this in PHP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to learn some basic PHP and programming terminology.

You don't need to add quotes around those values nor do you need to add a comma between them. You need to *create an array* with each value represented as a *string*. (Actually, you don't need them to be a string to insert them into the database but let's do it anyway.)

You can do this multiple ways. One is to use [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) to create the array and then [`array_map()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) and [`strval()`](http://ca.php.net/strval) to cast those values as strings.

```
$array = array_map('strval', explode(',', $_POST['chosen_zips']));
```

[<kbd>Demo</kbd>](https://eval.in/368432)

All you *really* need is:

```
$array = explode(',', $_POST['chosen_zips']);
```

[<kbd>Demo</kbd>](https://eval.in/368433)

Comment: Both of these statements give me `null` when I do a `var_dump`. I tested with this `$array =$_POST['chosen_zips'];` and it gives me the expected values. What am I missing here?

Comment: Ooops. Silly error. Fixed. Try again.

Comment: Perfect. That did the trick. I agree that I need to learn QUITE a bit more about PHP, so thanks for helping with one, as it definitely cleared some things up for me.